Spearguns without rubber?
I want a medieval civilization to be able to hunt under water. However every weapon I can find to spearfish under water seems to be rubber based. I don't want to introduce rubber to my world as it would have applications for many things as stated in the conclusion of this video. However bows and crossbows seem to have very poor performance under water due to their moving limbs being slowed down by the water. So I wondered if a spear gun or polespear could be created in other ways. For example by using springs which existed in the 15th century.

Spear fishing is a real thing, has been practiced for thousands of years, and it does not need any rubber. Or springs.

But to my understanding spear fishing historically was a fisher standing in or above the water with the spear above the surface and then thrusting down to catch the fish. Modern spear fishing on the other hand means diving down with a spear shooting weapon to hunt fish while swimming/diving. And while free diving to harvest clams, sponges and other slow seafood has been practiced for thousands of years. I never heard of divers hunting fast sea food in history.

The Bajau and other sea nomads just sent a note, they want to know why you think they don't exist? they've been spear fishing subsurface with nothing but spears for centuries.

Electric rays hunt subsurface w/out spearguns: consider taming them to hunt in raypacks. If you go that way, note a gold leaf wetsuit is better than no wetsuit.

You may prefer to stun fish with a toxic gas in stead of electricity. In which case, tame a herd of hippopotami and train them to fart synchronously in water. Add sagacious comments about the compared merits of different scuba technologies, for a nice Rabelaisian touch. (Sorry, I just had to suggest this one).

@Pelinore I actually didn't knew that. When I looked up spear fishing all results that came up where the above water kind or modern spear fishing. If you can recommend any sources to learn more about their culture and lifestyle especially around the middle ages please let me know.

@GreedyGroot well the Bajau were reported as early as the 1600s, (17th century) the modern ones seem to use sling spears or homemade spearguns that use rubber (bits of old inner tire etc) and though rubber has been known by some since as early as the 1600s (the Olmec?) they won't have had access to it back then, I 'assume' (but don't know) they were just using long thin spears, potentially with spear-throwers? before 1900s and maybe into the early and mid 1900s.

I suspect there are old black and white documentaries by the BBC or National Geographic articles that may show they're original kit but they're either not online or swamped by all the more modern material online because I can't find anything with the handful of search strings I've tried ;)

Using spear throwers from above water was used by many different cultures but I can't imagine that this works under water. Holding a stick in hand making a throw movement is way slower under water. Just holding a spear in hand and stabbing is probably faster as extending your arm produces less drag then rotating the extended arm. However I haven't even found evidence of people just stabbing with a spear underwater to hunt.

Same principles should apply under as well as over water, it's a force multiplier that provides extra leverage and thus force either way, I can actually see that being easier than propelling a lance or spear by hand underwater, but I'm also unsure ;) a thin enough spear won't experience overly much drag and can probably be propelled by one with sufficient force underwater, but simply using a long spear to jab may have been the technique of course.

The enlarged spleens are proof positive they've been spending a lot of time underwater and free diving long before now but there is other stuff to forage for down there so they may have done their fishing from above and have been diving for other resources of course, but at the same time I'm pretty sure I've seen old documentaries and the subsurface fishing isn't a modern development that only came in with the availability of rubber.

I think that it is feasible with cross-bow technology. You appear to dismiss that in your question, due to the effect of water resistance on the arms of the cros-bow. But I think that is only a problem because traditional crossbows are designed to shoot a fairly light projectile at a high speed over a large distance. A spear-fishing cross-bow would be accelerating a much heavier projectile to a much lower speed, so the arms do not need to move as fast and would therefore not suffer as much 'water-resistance'.
To make the comparison:
A traditional cross-bow accelerates a ~25 gramme bolt to a speed of ~80-100 m/s, with a practical range in excess of 100 m. To achieve this, the string is in contact with the bolt for a distance of 20-30 cm, so acceleration may be in excess of 1000 g.
A speargun spear weighs ~200 g and moves at a speed of ~30 m/s, with a practical range of less than 10 m. If a spear-bow was designed with slower-moving, and shorter but more flexible arms, it might be in contact with the spear for 30-50 cm, so acceleration would be around 100 g (so similar forces involved).
The tips of the arms of the spear-bow would have a maximum speed around a third of that of a traditional cross-bow, so (assuming v^2 friction), the water resistance on the arms could be reduced by at least an order of magnitude compared with those in a traditional cross-bow (if used underwater).

Getting bows or cross-bows wet in the medieval period was a no-no.  It led to the bows or their strings weakening, since they were made from natural materials such as wood, sinew and water-soluable glues.

I am assuming that the cross-bow would have to be built with metal arms and a twisted steel wire 'string'.

Then they'd rust.

You would have to carefully dry and oil them after each trip, or invent a suitable stainlees steel.

@MontyWild recent experimental archaeology has cast doubt on how much strings were affected by getting wet, despite the extensive documented evidence that it was a concern and archers went to great lengths to keep their strings dry.  And Penguino - not sure what you mean by "traditional", but crossbow bolts in ye olden days were 100-160 g or thereabouts.  Can't easily find speargun spear weights, but expect they would be heavier than 200 g in order to not lose speed too quickly in a much more resistant medium.

And on the other hand @KerrAvon2055 far too little "experimental archaeology" is done by anyone other than larpers pretending to know what they're talking about (aka, basically us) for the great majority of the field to be taken at all seriously ;) I've seen far too much really shoddy work riddled with confirmation bias called experimental archaeology b4 to take anything based on it seriously, would have to see the thing being done myself to judge it's quality b4 giving it any credence, on a case by case basis these days, and I always start by seriously doubting any work that calls itself that

@MontyWild What about brass or bronze?

@Ryan_L That might work.

You seem to be correct. This video (https://youtu.be/dMP3YtQ-mVU?si=9wydcMZRQQZXVHkl) made me think that archery under water doesn't work for hunting. But we can see here (https://youtu.be/MBIEcpUUgEM?si=shc_2HmCUJUcKmmk) that it actually can work. The range is just shorter then with spear guns.

Underwater crossbow can be made out of seaborne materials, like say, big fishbones, and kelp-fiber for the string which by definition do not suffer from water degradation just as fast.
